# How to adjust the space between Panel1 and Panel2 in a SplitContainer?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0, splitcontainer

How does one increase the size of the space separation between panels of a SplitContainer?

Comment: I can't add an image. I am a newbie and the rules God said I needed a 10 to post. But yes, when my mouse pointer is over the space windows hooks the line and lets me adjust the panel size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the value of the [SplitterWidth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.splitcontainer.splitterwidth.aspx) property.

e.g.:

```
splitContainer.SplitterWidth = 8;
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the padding of the container, see [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.splitcontainer.padding(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.splitcontainer.padding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Hmmm. Padding is for inside the Panel. I'm interested in the part between the Panels.